# Mutliple tor exit relays on the same router and dedicated WAN IP?

Tags: exit-relays

I have an extra adsl connection that I would like to dedicate to TOR.

I would like it to be very low power so will use a mixture of Rpi2 B(newer model) and B+ computers hooked up to ethernet switch and powered using a 7 port usb 2.0 hub.

I would like to know

1. Is it possible to run multiple relays on the same static WAN IP?
2. Will I need to forward different OR and DirectPorts for each system on my adsl router?
3. Is it benificial to the tor network in anyway by having this set up?

The reason for using more than one relay is because I already have one set up on my primary internet connection and no matter how much bandwidth I allocate to it, it only downloads 100Mb and uploads half that a day.

I intend to use 5 Rasperry Pis running headless raspbian or arch linux to accomplish this.

Comment: My guess is that your router is the bottleneck in your setup, not your relay machine. Consider purchasing a router that can handle more traffic instead of adding another relay behind the same router.

Comment: @ nullUser, Do you mean the router on my current relay? Im pretty sure it can handle all the traffic that comes through my WAN and then some more. Not the fasted internet but not slow either.Please can you explain a bit more. cheers

Comment: I've encountered a similar issue. I have have gigabit internet and corresponding gigabit router. Should be enough, right? Turns out no. The router is ISP mandated and has a maximum simultaneous connection limit of around 2000, maxing my relay out at around 10 Mbps.

Comment: The new RBP2's use up 1.21W, the old models use 1.89W. So that's somewhere between 6.05W and 9.45W. Just wanted to add that in.

The RBP1's were not able to max out a 100mbit connection in my testing. I'm sure the 2's will be better. So your setup does make sense(ish).